# Bug with unformatted code false positive

Tags: bug

I was unable to submit an edit because it claims the following contains unformatted code. The only part I added was " (although keep in mind this will be incorrect for a few weeks around daylight savings changes)"

---

Try the [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (`shipped_products`)
WHERE HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, 'UTC', 'America/New York')) = 8
```

The manual warns:

> ### Note
>
> To use named time zones such as `'MET'` or `'Europe/Moscow'`, the time zone tables must be properly set up. [See Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), for instructions.

You can also use hour values instead (although keep in mind this will be incorrect for a few weeks around daylight savings changes):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (`shipped_products`)
WHERE HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-05:00')) = 8
```

Comment: Can you link to the post you tried to edit?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Looks like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363329/mysql-hour-accounting-for-timezones/34363364#34363364)

Comment: Hmm.  Weird.  Is it possible this would only occur for suggestions and not full edits?

Comment: I'm more willing to think that a firewall is at play.